# JS Div not changing color when arrow key is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Right, this is weird, I have no idea why this is happening, but what I am doing is I have a search field where a user inputs a name and I would like it to display suggestions, now this is working but when the user uses the arrow keys (up or down) the objects should hilight, basically like a standard autocomplete just with a different design.

The problem is the hilighting bit, when I press the down arrow, the object get's hlighted aslong as I hold the arrow key down, but it's not staying hilighted. I can't figure out why, I've posted the relevant code below, I hope someone can help:

**main file (textfield):**

```
<div style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: -51px; width: 200px;">
    <form method="GET" action="" style="padding: 0px; padding-right: 10px; margin: 0px;">
         <input type="text" id="search_field" onkeyup="javascript: suggestions(this.value);" autocomplete="off" style="border: 0px solid #ffffff; width: 250px; padding-left: 20px; color: #ffffff; height: 30px; border-bottom: 1px solid #333333; background: #222222;" name="q" placeholder="Search MVDb">
    </form>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 2px; top: 8px;">
    <img height="15" src="img/search.png">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="result" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; cursor: pointer; top: 86px; right: 5px; width: 251px; background: #eeeeee;">

</div>
```

the div with the id result is where the suggestions get loaded into.

**main file (jquery/js):**

```
function suggestions(value){
     $.ajax({
         url: 'get_suggestion.php?q='+value,
         success: function(data) {
            $('#result').html(data);    
         }
     });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search_field").keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 40) { 
           //DOWN
           document.getElementById('search_result_0').style.background = "#333333";
           e.preventDefault();
           return false;
       }
    else if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
        //UP
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
   }
   });      
});
```

**get_suggestion.php:**

```
<?php 
include 'js/db/db.php';
$value = $_GET["q"];
if($value==""){

}
else{
    $value = trim($value);
    $query="select * from movies where title like \"%$value%\" LIMIT 6";  
    $rt=mysql_query($query);
    echo mysql_error();  
    $counter = -1;
    while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($rt)){
        $counter = $counter+1;
?>
<div id="search_result_<?php echo $counter ?>" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" onClick="window.location = 'movie.php?movie=<?php echo $nt['title']?>'" width="100%" style="color: #333333; cursor: pointer;">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr valign="top">
            <td style="padding: 5px; width: 30px;">
                <img height="60" src="http://210.177.0.75/mvdb/img/covers/<?php echo $nt['title'] ?>.jpg">
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="padding: 5px;">
                <?php
                    $title = substr($nt[title], 0, 17);
                    if($title == $nt[title]){

                    }
                    else{
                        $title = $title."...";
                    }   
                ?>
                <font style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $title ?></font> &nbsp; <img src="img/age/BBFC <?php echo $nt['bbfc_age'] ?>_small.png"><br>
                <font style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; color: #aaaaaa;">Tom Cruise, Michelle Monaga</font>
                <font style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; color: #aaaaaa;">Released: 4 May 2006</font>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<?php
}  
  }
  ?>
```

I've tried to format the code as well as possible. I thought it could be that when the user presses the arrow key the ajax request get's triggered but this wouldn't make any sense as I am using e.preventDefault() to stop this, does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right about the arrow key executing the ajax request. You've used `e.preventDefault` in the keydown function but not in the keyup one. Instead of an `onkeyup` attribute, I would suggest you put this right below your keydown function:

```
$("#search_field").keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode < 41 && e.keyCode > 36) {
        suggestions(this.val());
    }
});
```

That should it out.

Comment: okay :) I managed to solve this seconds before you posted your answer, but yes I just realised that as well... stupid me. Thanks for clearing it up and spending time reading the rather long question though :)